# Are 'derive from' and 'be derived from' always interchangeable?

Tags: usage

For example,

- Petroleum ***is derived from*** coal tar.
- Petroleum ***derives from*** coal tar.

Is the latter grammatically correct?
When I referred to dictionaries, they don't list examples of ***derive from*** as an intransitive verb to mean ***to produce or obtain (a compound) from another substance by chemical reaction[[The American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=derive&submit.x=16&submit.y=34)]***.

Answer (score 2):

The normal usage of derive is of the form

> *beneficiary* derives *benefit* from ...

When it is not necessary or useful to identify the beneficiary, passive voice can be used:

> *benefit* is derived from ...

An intransitive form is largely undocumented but, according to this [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=derives%20from%2Cis%20derived%20from%2Cderives%20from%20_NOUN_%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), it is widely used:

> *benefit* derives from ...

This usage is more in keeping with the etymological origins of the word, which means flow (river comes from the same origin). As the Ngram graph shows, the intransitive usage suffered a decline in popularity, reaching an all-time low in 1920: it is possible that the dictionaries have not kept up with its resurgence.

Comment: Merriam-Webster lists the intransitive version under [derive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/derive), which I would call being documented.

Comment: You'd have to assess how many of the **derives from** attestations in Ngram are actually versions of your first category, "*beneficiary* derives *benefit* from [*source*]", as  in  "X derives from *source* a number of benefits".

Comment: @TimR I have updated the NGram graph.  instances of "X derives from source a" do occur but are insignificant.

Comment: @JavaLatte Does the _NOUN_ directive include noun phrases? And is there something like _DETERMINER_ that would catch phrases like "dervices several benefits..."?  Not that this would make a significant difference--just curious about the features of Ngram I hadn't been aware of.

Comment: @TimR For more information about Goolge NGrams, open the Ngram graph and then click on **About Ngram Viewer** in the bottom left corner of the page.

Comment: Thanks. Never saw that link at the bottom  of the page as it was always below the bottom of my screen and I didn't even know it was there!